# pandas drop row if column contains string

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file as follow:

```
message,name,userID,period,@timestamp,timediff
messagebody,Request URL,system,period_8,2021-05-10 09:21:31,1
messagebody,Request URL,system,period_9,2021-05-10 09:58:19,1
"Failed Logon for user ""user""",Logon Attempt,user,period_1,2021-05-10 08:00:22,1
"Failed Logon for user ""user""",Logon Attempt,user,period_1,2021-05-09 05:59:34,1
```

I am trying to check check the `userID` and remove all the rows that contains `system`

I tried with:

```
f['userID'] = f[~f["userID"].str.contains("system", na=False)]
```

But it doesn't seem to drop the rows.

Just a little explanation about the columns userID

This column is the result of a merge of other 2 columns.

```
f['userID'] = f[['destinationUserName','sourceUserName']].astype(str).agg(''.join,1).replace('nan','',regex=True)
f['userID'] = f[~f["userID"].str.contains("system", na=False)]
```

if I run my script I get this error:

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 239 elements, new values have 252 elements
```

Can anyone help me to understand how to overcome this issue?

How can I target that column and remove specific rows that contains a specific string.

thank you so much for any help

Comment: Why you are assigning that to column 'userID'? just simply do `f=f[~f["userID"].str.contains("system", na=False)]`

Comment: That worked. If you want to add it as an answer I can upvote it :) Thank you

Comment: Thanks Sir for this...It is not necessary..Happy coding **:)**